# Suggestion to choose correct WCF Instance Mode

Tags: wcf, serialization

I am Balu from Hyderabad. I have writing WCF Restful services for our Andriod / Iphone developers()They can use JSON format so that we are choosing REST). Actually we can do Mobile Application only one APP that can runs differnt projects. All the projects are dynamically comes from WEBSERVICE to MobileApp. So we can configure all the dynamic data from Web services only.

Only one App can handle 5 projects having totally 100-150 users. so i can write only one service using Factory Reflection methods to load projects dynamically.

Q) I have doubt that for our projects which WCF instance mode is suitable?
By reading WCF instance mode articles i understand that "percall" instance is suitable for our WCF service. Is my guess correctly or not? Please suggest me.
And i have one more doubt that If we are not specify an attribute as serialize then that object will not go through network properly? i have tried without serialization (i.e not mentioned "datamember" for particular property) its going well to Mobile App.
Please clarify my doubts and tell me whih instance mode i have to use?

1. Which instance is better?
2. Which ConcurrencyMode is better?

Answer (score 1):

The **PerCall** instance mode is preferred when you don't need to maintain state between calls for the same client.  In other words, your service is stateless.  **PerInstance** is used when you need to maintain some state between calls for a client.  And finally, **Singleton** is used when you need to reference state between multiple clients. Depending on your binding and security settings, you will default to either PerCall or PerInstance.  PerCall is ideal because it's easier for you to scale your service if/when you need to.

For your ConcurrencyMode, the default is single threaded.  Since you're asking, I would suggest leaving this as the default (generally).  However, take a look at the tricky case I talked about [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx).

The [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes are not necessary as of .NET Framework 3.5.  Prior to that version, you had to be explicit and specify these attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually we are validating user session by user Loginid with relevant project code. We are sending these two with every request.So i think this is also to be persistent.
 
I have tried with out putting [DataContract] to class but i put [Datamember] for that class property. The property is worked as serialized and i got the value also. Shall we put [Datamember] without mentioned the class as [DataContract]??